# SSL Error on Curl AIX

Tags: curl, aix

Hi guys I'm fairly new to curl and connectivity. I'm encountering an issue below using curl command:

curl https://example.com/realms/apigw-auth-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to examples.com:443

I've tried importing the root certificate from the where the example.com resides using:

keytool -import -file root.crt -alias CertAuth -keystore "keystorefile"

But it didn't help. Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

I'm on AIX 7.2

curl 7.44.0 (powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0) libcurl/7.44.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2u zlib/1.2.12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019

Curl -v result:

```bash
curl -v https://example.com/realms/apigw-auth-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token
*   Trying 10.110.255.70...
* Connected to example.com (10.110.255.70) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.com:443
```

Comment: No support for TLS1.3? No support for some of the encryption types? Adding the `-v` switch to curl should give you more info. All of AIX, curl & openssl are old and do not support current standards.

Comment: Your curl is eight and your OpenSSL nearly nine years old. It's thoroughly possible your server is not supporting any of the potentially insecure older SSL modes that these libraries night be configured to use. Run with `-v` to get more information about where it fails. Is upgrading to a newer version of AIX an option? I suspect they would have less ancient OpenSSL.

Comment: Adding a certificate to a java keystore will not help, as `curl` is not a Java program and does not use the keystore.

Comment: Hey, CLRR, could you please share the output of `curl -v https://example.com/realms/apigw-auth-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token`? Otherwise, we can't help you, because we're missing necessary information.

Comment: I'd suggest trying some of the possibilities in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20492254/4957508

Comment: You can also try to get more information with `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443`; is there a proxy involved?

Comment: Hi guys added the -v flag. I suppose this is a curl version issue rather than connection issues?

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller, return code is - Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

Comment: b@eth6:~/Downloads> openssl x509 -text -in DigiCertTLSRSASHA2562020CA1-1.crt.pem 
`Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            06:d8:d9:04:d5:58:43:46:f6:8a:2f:a7:54:22:7e:c4
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 14 00:00:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Apr 13 23:59:59 2031 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1`

Update your cert store.

Comment: To test if it is a certificate-problem, use curl option `-k`.